# Redireccionar tras 5 segundos del click en wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Bajo CMS Wordpress lo que busco es que tras 5 segundos de haber hecho click en un boton concreto la página se redireccione a otra url obtenida por una variable php.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function sample() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       window.open('<?php echo esc_attr(wpcoupon_coupon()->get_go_out_url()); ?>', '_self');
   }, 5000); 
}
</script>
```

Y en el boton:

```
<button class="ui right labeled icon button btn btn_secondary" onClick="sample();">
<i class="copy icon"></i>
<span><?php esc_html_e('Copy', 'wp-coupon'); ?></span>
```

El asunto es que en un archivo php fuera de wordpress y variando del script `<?php echo esc_attr(wpcoupon_coupon()->get_go_out_url()); ?>` por http://www.google.com funciona correctamente, pero al integrar los códigos en single.php la url a la que redirecciona es example.com/nombre-de-la-entrada/url
, añadiendo ese ultimo url al ejecutarse la redirección.
He probado a mostrar mediante php `<?php echo esc_attr(wpcoupon_coupon()->get_go_out_url()); ?>` y la url que nuestra es correcta.

Muchas Gracias de antemano

Comment: te has fijado si llega correctamente la url a javascript? proba mostrarla con un `console.log()`

Answer (score 0):

Hola esto lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
?>
```

otra manera es coloca una etiqueta meta en en la pagina php destino

```
//redirecciona en 10 segundos
<meta http-equiv=""refresh content="10,url=http://example.com"/>
```

otra manera es que uses javascripts, pero si usan un bloqueador de script te lo anulara

```
    //primero el php
    <?php
    header ("refresh:10; url=https://example.com/index.php");
    ?>

        //Ahora agregas el javascript
        <script>
        (function() {
        var timeleft = 10,
        cinterval;

        var timeDec = function (){
        timeLeft--;
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = timeleft;
        if(timeleft === 0){
        clearInterval(cinterval);
           }
        };
        cinterval = setInterval(timeDec, 1000);
        })();

        </script>

// te agregare el enlace porque algunas veces me preguntan 
//el procedimiento, creas el estilo del boton con CSS

<?php 
echo "<a href="ir.php" class=\"boton\">Boton</a>";
//ir.php tiene toda la funcion de temporizacion
?>
```

Me avisas como te funciono

Answer (score 0):

php cuenta con una funcion llamada `sleep` esta disponible desde la version 4

**un ejemplo de como usarlo**

```
<?php

// current time
echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";

// sleep for 10 seconds
sleep(10);

// wake up !
echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";

?>
```

aqui te dejo el [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) de la documentacion